# Applying Multiple Window Functions On Same Partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Is it possible to apply multiple window functions to the same partition? (Correct me if I'm not using the right vocabulary)

For example you can do

```
SELECT name, first_value() over (partition by name order by date) from table1
```

But is there a way to do something like:

```
SELECT name, (first_value() as f, last_value() as l (partition by name order by date)) from table1
```

Where we are applying two functions onto the same window?

Reference:
http://postgresql.ro/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Can you not just use the window per selection

Something like

```
SELECT  name, 
        first_value() OVER (partition by name order by date) as f, 
        last_value() OVER (partition by name order by date) as l 
from table1
```

Also from your reference you can do it like this

```
SELECT sum(salary) OVER w, avg(salary) OVER w
FROM empsalary
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC)
```

Comment: Is it still the most efficient query when the number of `PARTITION BY` increases ?

Comment: You need to use parameter in first_value() and last_value(). I guess it should be _date_.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou according to the Postgres documentation, using the exact same `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses will guarantee that all window functions will use the same single pass over the data.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW

Answer (score 18):

***Warning :*** I don't delete this answer since it seems technically correct and therefore may be helpful, but **beware** that `PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo` is **probably not what you want to do** anyway.  Indeed, aggregate functions won't compute the partition elements as a whole.  That is, `SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo)` **is not equivalent** to `SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar)` (see proof at the end of the answer).

Though it doesn't improve performance *per se*, if you use multiple times the same partition, you probably **want** to use the second syntax proposed by astander, and not only because it's cheaper to write.  Here is why.

Consider the following query :

```
SELECT 
  array_agg(foo)
    OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo), 
  avg(baz)
    OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo) 
FROM 
  foobar;
```

Since in principle the ordering has no effect on the computation of the average, you might be tempted to use the following query instead (no ordering on the second partition) :

```
SELECT 
  array_agg(foo) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo), 
  avg(baz)
    OVER (PARTITION BY bar) 
FROM 
  foobar;
```

This is a **big mistake**, as it will take much longer.  Proof :

```
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT array_agg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo), avg(baz) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo) FROM foobar;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 WindowAgg  (cost=215781.92..254591.76 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=969.659..2353.865 rows=1724882 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=215781.92..220094.12 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=969.640..1083.039 rows=1724882 loops=1)
         Sort Key: bar, foo
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 130006kB
         ->  Seq Scan on foobar  (cost=0.00..37100.82 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=0.027..393.815 rows=1724882 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 2458.969 ms
(6 lignes)

> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT array_agg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo), avg(baz) OVER (PARTITION BY bar) FROM foobar;
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 WindowAgg  (cost=215781.92..276152.79 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=938.733..2958.811 rows=1724882 loops=1)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=215781.92..250279.56 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=938.699..2033.172 rows=1724882 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=215781.92..220094.12 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=938.683..1062.568 rows=1724882 loops=1)
               Sort Key: bar, foo
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 130006kB
               ->  Seq Scan on foobar  (cost=0.00..37100.82 rows=1724882 width=12) (actual time=0.028..377.299 rows=1724882 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 3060.041 ms
(7 lignes)
```

Now, if you are aware of this issue, of course you will use the same partition everywhere.  But when you have ten times or more the same partition and you are updating it over days, it is quite easy to forget to add the `ORDER BY` clause on a partition which doesn't need it by itself.

Here comes the `WINDOW` syntax, which will prevent you from such careless mistakes (provided, of course, you're aware it's better to minimize the number of different window functions).  The following is strictly equivalent (as far as I can tell from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) to the first query :

```
SELECT
  array_agg(foo)
    OVER qux,
  avg(baz)
    OVER qux
FROM
  foobar
WINDOW
  qux AS (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY bar)
```

### Post-warning update :

*I understand the statement that "*`SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo)` **is not equivalent** to `SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar)`*" seems questionable, so here is an example :*

```
# SELECT * FROM foobar;
 foo | bar 
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   2 |   2
   3 |   1
   4 |   2
(4 lines)

# SELECT array_agg(foo) OVER qux, avg(foo) OVER qux FROM foobar WINDOW qux AS (PARTITION BY bar);
 array_agg | avg 
-----------+-----
 {1,3}     |   2
 {1,3}     |   2
 {2,4}     |   3
 {2,4}     |   3
 (4 lines)

# SELECT array_agg(foo) OVER qux, avg(foo) OVER qux FROM foobar WINDOW qux AS (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo);
 array_agg | avg 
-----------+-----
 {1}       |   1
 {1,3}     |   2
 {2}       |   2
 {2,4}     |   3
(4 lines)
```

Comment: In the warning, it's said, "That is, SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo) is not equivalent to SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar)." **Why is it not?**

Comment: I can hardly believe `SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY foo)` is *NOT* equivalent to `SELECT avg(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY bar)` as far we're discussing result set. Please prove, they differ. The execution time may of course vary (as you build two unnamed windows instead of one), but results are still the same.

Comment: @Cromax Just run the `WINDOW` command of my answer on this minimal example : `create table foobar(foo float, bar int); insert into foobar values (1,1); insert into foobar values (3,1);`, with and without the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Nick I'm not into SQL anymore enough to reliably answer the why, but try the example in my previous comment (maybe add some lines to make it more obvious), the `array_agg()` output will give some hint.

Comment: @Skippy Damn, you've changed my understanding of `PARTITION`, thanks! (For those interested: with `ORDER BY` it returns rows of {1; 2}, and without it returns {2; 2}.

Comment: THANK YOU. I understand now. Here's another pretty good example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html. Then, the `ORDER BY` sorts the rows within the window, and processes them in that order including only the current and previously seen rows, ignoring rows that are after current or not in the window.